# Conflict of between powerdot and listings packages

Tags: listings, powerdot

Playing with powerdot presentations, I realized one more awkward behavior. When `listings` package is in effect, `\onslide` command of `powerdot` package does not seem robust.

The minimum example is shown below. The awkwardness could be explained such at its best:

> When `listings` package is loaded and even number of `\onslide` commands define overlay indexes as a range, the last `\onslide` command does not produce output.

Anything that may possibly fix the range definition?

```
\documentclass[mode=present, style=horatio]{powerdot}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\avf}[1][1]{\pdifsetup{present}{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}}{}}% alternating vertical fill

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Sample}\avf
  --
  \onslide*{1-2}{
    ab
  }
  --
  \onslide*{3-4}{
    cd
  }
  --
\avf\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea when I was writing the question. (This should be the rubber duck debugging in action.)

As far as I understood, the `\onslide` command would like to consume the range definition. During this, if you've put content in this defined range, it disappears.

I came up with this solution first:

```
\documentclass[mode=present, style=horatio]{powerdot}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\avf}[1][1]{\pdifsetup{present}{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}}{}}% alternating vertical fill

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Sample}\avf
  \onslide*{0-0}{}
  --
  \onslide*{1-2}{
    ab
  }
  --
  \onslide*{3-4}{
    cd
  }
  --
\avf\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Define a dummy range at the beginning. This may be done by defining a range to zeroth overlay to zeroth overlay with no content. This fixes the problem by making the number of range definitions odd again. However, you may not want to check the number of `\onslide` commands each time you update the content.

Then, I thought of a better idea.

```
\documentclass[mode=present, style=horatio]{powerdot}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\avf}[1][1]{\pdifsetup{present}{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}}{}}% alternating vertical fill

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Sample}\avf
  --
  \onslide*{1-2}{
    ab
  }
  --
  \onslide*{3-4}{
    cd
  }
  --
  \onslide*{5,6}{
    ef
  }
  --
\avf\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

The solution is to define the final `\onslide` range as a comma separated list of overlays. I'd prefer to choose to modify the final as it fixes all previous range definitions (independent of being even or odd numbered). For example, if you redefine the first range as a comma separated list, you may still leave even number of range definitions afterwards.